# How many different ways of placing five individuals in 7 chairs in a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the answer $\binom{7}{5}$ ? Is this the same as placing 5 books in a 7 shelf bookcase ?

Comment: Are the chairs numbered ?

Comment: The question doesn't  mention that, but I think they are not numbered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably rotations of the circle will be considered the same.

Consider one of the five people special.  Pick him according to your favorite quantifier (the shortest, youngest, tallest, smartest, etc...).

Let him sit at the table in any position, it matters not where.

Among the remaining four people, let them pick each pick a seat in turn (again, according to your favorite way to order them: shortest to tallest, alphabetically, etc...).

Let the five people be labeled $A,B,C,D,E$ and the ordering of the people is in the usual way.

$A$ takes his seat.

How many choices for seats does $B$ have available?

How many choices for seats does $C$ have available?

$\vdots$

Apply multiplication principle for the result.

> $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3=360$

An alternate way to see this result is to temporarily assume the circle is instead a straight line.  Pick which five of the seats are occupied and pick the order in which the people appear.  Then divide by the number of times we will have overcounted each scenario.  This comes from an application of [burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma) noting that the only group action that fixes any arrangements is the identity.

> $\binom{7}{5}5!\cdot \frac{1}{7}=360$

---

In the case that the chairs are distinguishable somehow and rotations are not considered the same:

Pick which chair $A$ sits in.  Pick which chair $B$ sits in... Apply multiplication principle.

> $7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 7\cdot 360$

Comment: Ok. One more question. Can I just turn the circle into a straight line?

Comment: @LigeBao added the interpretation where you temporarily assume the circle as a straight line above.

Comment: @LigeBao: Seating in a straight line is the same as seating in a *numbered* circle.

Answer (score 0):

If the chairs are numbered, $^7P_5$,

if they are not numbered, $^7P_5 \div 7$, since rotations  don't affect their relative position.

[ If unfamiliar with this notation, as $^7C_5$ stands for combinations, $^7P_5$ stands for permutations ]